# Subsetting dataset using multiple entries in Shiny gives incorrect output

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, data.table

I'm creating a `Shiny` application and I've run into a problem when choosing multiple inputs in a `selectizeInput` box and trying to subset my data using those choices.

Here is the intended output

```
testDT <- data.table(
    L = (1:32), 
    M = rep(letters[23:26], each = 64), 
    N = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 2, each = 512),
    O = rnorm(2048, 1))

testDT$L <- factor(testDT$L, levels = seq(from = 1, to = 32, by = 1))

ggplot(testDT, aes(L,O)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = N)) +  
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title=element_blank()) + 
    facet_grid(M ~ ., scales = "free") +
    labs(x = "L", y = "O")
```

However, when I create the application, the graph output is not as intended. The more options I select, for example in `N`, it seems as if the data begins to alternate.

Here's the `ui.R` file:

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(

            titlePanel("Test Application"),

            sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(

                            selectizeInput("N",
                                    label = ("N"),
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    choices = NULL,
                                    options = list(
                                            placeholder = 'Select All Desired, Type to Search',
                                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                    )),

                            selectizeInput("M", 
                                    label = "M",
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    choices = NULL,
                                    options = list(
                                            placeholder = 'Select All Desired, Type to Search',
                                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                    ))
                    ),

                    mainPanel(
                            tabsetPanel(
                                    tabPanel("Test Plot 1",
                                            plotOutput("testPlot1")),
                                    tabPanel("Test Plot 2",
                                            plotOutput("testPlot2"))


                    )
            ))))
```

And here is the `server.R` file:

```
# server.R

library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

testDT <- data.table(
    L = (1:32), 
    M = rep(letters[23:26], each = 64), 
    N = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 2, each = 512),
    O = rnorm(2048, 1))

testDT$L <- factor(testDT$L, levels = seq(from = 1, to = 32, by = 1))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

        updateSelectizeInput(session, "N", 
                server = TRUE, 
                choices = sort(unique(testDT$N)),
        )

        updateSelectizeInput(session, "M", 
                server = TRUE, 
                choices = unique(testDT$M),
        )       

        testDT1 <- reactive({
                    subset(testDT, N == input$N)
                })

        testDT2 <- reactive({
                    subset(testDT, N == input$N & M == input$M)
                })

        output$testTable <- renderDataTable(testDT1())

        output$testPlot1 <- renderPlot({

                    p <- ggplot(testDT1(), aes(L,O)) +
                            geom_boxplot(aes(fill = N)) +  
                            theme_bw() +
                            theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title=element_blank()) + 
                            facet_grid(M ~ ., scales = "free") +
                            labs(x = "L", y = "O")
                    print(p)
                })

        output$testPlot2 <- renderPlot({

                    p <- ggplot(testDT2(), aes(L,O)) +
                            geom_boxplot(aes(fill = N)) +  
                            theme_bw() +
                            theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title=element_blank()) + 
                            facet_grid(M ~ ., scales = "free") +
                            labs(x = "L", y = "O")
                    print(p)
                })
    })
```

I have a strong suspicion that I am subsetting the data incorrectly, but as I am new to the `Shiny` environment, I don't fully understand the behavior when subsetting using an `input$_____` call, like below.

```
testDT1 <- reactive({
      subset(testDT, N == input$N)
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use subsetting from `[` operator instead of `subset` function.
Read SO question [In R, why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) for more details on that.
In your example:

```
testDT1 <- reactive({
      testDT[eval(call("==", as.name("N"), input$N))]
})
```

Change `==` to `%in%` for multi value subset.

Also be aware it may be worth to use data.table index as it can dramatically speed up filtering, so gives real-time filtering for your shiny application. For more details see my blog post [Scaling data.table using index](https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-11-23/data.table-index.html).
In fact index should be created automatically during the first filtering, you may prepare it after loading your dataset with `set2keyv` function.

Comment: Can you provide a method to use data.table.index for this example? I'm very curious about it.

Comment: @black_sheep07 there is no specific method, read linked blog post for more details on data.table index, including usage and usage tracking.

Comment: I am now using `data.table.index` but the speed bottleneck is most definitely in `ggplot2`, not the indexing. I will be using this going forward, so thanks for the heads up!